# jquery show() function delays

Tags: jquery, queue, show

I am using `jquery.show()` to show the div which was `"display:none"` in css.
However, the `show()` function delays to show the div.

```
function button_click(){
    $("#mydiv").show();
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

I tried like `$('#mydiv').show({queue:false})` but it does not work.
The #mydiv shows only when the function1 and function2 are finished.
How to make the `show()` works immediately?

update: i found it was because that I use $.ajxaSetup({async:false}). 
I need to make multiple request like $.get and I do something after all requests finish so I made it async... but in this way the $.show() function does not work until all request finish...

Comment: And what function1 and function2 do?

Comment: `.show('fast')`  Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your actual file but based on you code here's my solution using a simple callback the function `one` and `two` won't run until they're called by the `main` function which is a callback of `hide` method:

```js
function button_click(){
 function one() { console.log('I am one');}
 function two() { console.log('I am two');}
 
 $("#mydiv1").hide('slow', function main(){
  one();
  two();
  });
}


button_click();
```

```css
.child {
 color           : white;
 display         : inline-block;
 margin          : 20px;
   
 min-width       : 50px;
 min-height      : 50px;
 padding         : 10px;
 background-color: olive;
  }
  
.parent {
 padding         : 20px;
 background-color: beige;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="father" class="parent">
     <div id="mydiv1" class="child">1</div>
     <div id="mydiv2" class="child">2</div>
     <div id="mydiv3" class="child">3</div>
     <div id="mydiv4" class="child">4</div>
     <div id="mydiv5" class="child">5</div>
   </div>
```

I hope this helps